# What are service end points in MSCRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Tech Friends,

What are service end points in MSCRM 2011?

When I open a solution in MSCRM 2011, I see a separate a separate feature in left panel which is named as "Service end points". I did not find much documentation about the same and also how do we add new service end points?

Comment: From the SDK: A service endpoint represents a Windows Azure platform endpoint. (The Service End Point component) stores the configuration information of a service endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Name endpoint comes from [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessagingEndpointsIntro.html). You can work with CRM through user interface it provides for you, but there is other option. Your own software is able to interact with CRM, as with service. Interaction goes through the messages, your client software sends to CRM services. So, in this case both, software you are working on and CRM will have endpoints. Your software will have client endpoints, but CRM will have server endpoints. I don't think you need to add new endpoints in CRM, because there are already defined. Just use them sending messages from your code.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer seems to be helpful but here is the response in MSDN Forums which says the endpoints are required for integration with Windows Azure.

Link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/5fa85ef2-1f6e-44f6-9752-dea120f9d9d0